# Certificate Error Occurs When Associating Desktop Application with Microsoft Partner Center

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, certificate

### Definition Of The Problem

I have the components specified in the [documen](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/samples/microsoft/diceweb/sample-partner-center-apps-uwp-cpp/)t for testing applications:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 (Version 16.8.4)
- Windows 10 SDK (Version 2004 - 10.0.19041.0) - SignTool.exe
- Microsoft Partner Center Account (Individual Account)

However, I'm having a certificate problem while associating the application with Microsoft Partner Center via Visual Studio IDE.

### Steps Followed

The steps I follow in associating the desktop application with the Microsoft Partner Center are as follows:

1. Cloning of the project from the remote repository.
2. The opening of the project solution (DiceWebSampleApps_vs2019.sln) in Visual Studio IDE.
3. Downloading the signable file (SignableFile.bin) from the Microsoft Partner Center.
4. Calling SignTool.exe from the command line to sign the file. Since SignTool.exe takes a PFX file as an argument, I used the certificate generation tool on the Visual Studio IDE. I copied the PFX file to the directory where the SignTool.exe tool will be run.

   a. I opened a certificate selection window on Visual Studio IDE.

   `Screenshot 1`: [Visual Studio IDE Certificate Selection Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4JBA.png)

   b. I clicked the "Create" button to create a new certificate.

   `Screenshot 2`: [Create New Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6sbZ.png)

   c. I created a new certificate. I uploaded the certificate (*.pfx file) created in the current directory.

   `Screenshot 3`: [Choose A New Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0S3l.png)

   d. I chose the new certificate created.

   `Screenshot 4`: [Viewing The New Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMNvC.png)
5. I called the SignTool.exe tool from the command line to mark the SignableFile.bin file. When I ran the command I thought everything was fine.

   `Screenshot 5`: [Marking The SignableFile.bin File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFcM0.png)

```
.\signtool.exe sign /f .\<company_name>.pfx /p <password> /v .\SignableFile.bin
```

6. I ran the following command to verify the marked file. The verification command returned the following error:

   `Screenshot 6`: [Marking The SignableFile.bin File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSys4.png)

```
.\signtool.exe verify /a .\SignableFile.bin
```

7. I got the following error when I tried to drag the SignableFile.bin file, which was marked ignoring the verification error, to the Microsoft Partner Center:

   `Screenshot 7`: [Error Warning Shown On Microsoft Partner Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwrsG.png)

### Help Request

I don't know enough about certificate management in Windows 10. Therefore, I tried many methods but couldn't be successful. The SignTool.exe tool and Microsoft Partner Center generated similar errors. I tried using the X.509 key pair, which is short-term and reliable to run. But the Root Certificate Manager gave the same error.

I think this might be because I'm an individual user. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: The error in Partner Center tells you everything you need to know - a self-signed certificate that you just created on your own machine won't be sufficient, you need to have you certificate signed by a trusted CA. Follow the link, find the list of trusted CA providers and contact one of them for a signing certificate

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Link directs me to the same page. But I found a list of trusted certificate providers at [TechRadar](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-ssl-certificate-provider). I guess the reason the link directs me to the same page is that I need to request a signed certificate from the CA within the company. I need to obtain a certificate for myself as I work independently for this project. Thanks again.